# What can I use instead of setImageResource() to work on API lower than 16?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

I added an ImageView to my layout and I want to set it's resource programatically. I tried to do it like this:

```
reklamniBanner.setImageResource(R.drawable.reklama_test);
```

But it doesn't let me do it because setImageResource() only works on API level 16 or higher while I'm supporting 11+

Is there another function I could use instead of setImageResource for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setImageResource(int resId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) is available from API 1 and not API 16. Try cleaning your project, restarting your IDE etc.

Comment: Wow...weird. Never happened to me before. It said it requires minimum API 16 but it disappeared after I cleaned the project. Thank you!